# What are "Exportable" entities in Guidewire?

Tags: entities, guidewire

Can you explain what are "Exportable" entities in guidewire? How can we create these entities? Also explain what is the difference between Extendable entities, Exportable entities and Final Entities?

Want to Know the difference of the Entity types.

Answer (score 2):

Detailed information is available in the Guidewire product documentation.

For quick reference -

1. Exportable entities can be exported from one environment to another. Basically it makes them available to be exported from Admin. You can define this when you create an entity as one of the properties.
2. Extendable entities - ClaimCenter extensions allow you to add new fields to the base data entities. You can add custom fields to extendable entities only. Not all entities are extendable, but most of the important business entities such as Claim, User, Contact, and others are extendable. It is generally for OOTB entities.
3. Final entity - This is the opposite of extendable entity. You cannot subtype/extend this entity with additional fields and attributes.

Comment: #Exportable means you can publish the entity through an API.

Answer (score 1):

**exportable** also means that it become part of the published API for that entity.  This can be at the entity level as well as the column level.

with **final**, if true, you can't create a subtype from it but you can still extend the entity with properties in an etx as well as enhancements to the entity